# Avoid multiples resources downloads of the same JNLP?

Tags: java, jnlp

I had a app based on JNLP, but every time when the user click in JNLP file, the new Download happen, and the file is greater than 80mb.

I read all documentation, the file is signed with a trust cert from DigiCert.

But the jar file are downloaded over and over, but this sometimes after a few executions, but nothing are change in app.

We use the oracle recommendation, how describe in documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#update

Attribute:

```
check attribute: The check attribute indicates the preference for when the JNLP Client should check for updates, and can have one of the three values: "always", "timeout", and "background"
```

Used Value:

```
A value of "always" means to always check for updates before launching the application.
```

Attribute:

```
policy attribute: The policy attribute indicates the preference for how the JNLP Client should handle an application update when it is known an update is available before the application is launched, and can have one of the following three values: "always", "prompt-update", and "prompt-run
```

Used Value:

```
A value of "always" (default) means to always download updates without any prompt.
```

My great doubt is in this place of documentation "when it is known an update is available before the application is launched", how they know the app need to be updated, and if the JNLP are the same, and the app in server are the same too, why they update.

We use too the oracle recomendation to avoid unnecessary update:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/avoidingUnnecessaryUpdateChecks.html

The server is not static content, the JNLP are generate everytime user needs, but the content are the same, we think this is a problem with file generation, but when we use the same file to simulate scenario sending to user with no generation he still download the file.

The strange thing is in the local server are working, without dowloads.

I try to use version, codebase, but is not clear to me, the parameters java use to determine when some resource in JNLP are updated.

My JNLP file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.5+" codebase="http://www.orgen.com.br/jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>orgen-client</title>
        <vendor>AtlanticaSoft</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.orgen.com.br" />
        <description>Aplicação cliente Orgen</description>
        <icon href="icon.png" kind="default" />
    </information>  
    <update check="always" policy="always" />
    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>  
    <resources>
         <j2se version="1.8+" initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="512m" java-vm-args="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m" />
         <jar href="lib/orgen-client.jar" version="1.0" main="true" />
         <jar href="lib/orgen-client-dependency.jar" version="1.0" />
         <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="br.com.atlanticasoft.orgen.client.Main" />
</jnlp>
```

My JNLP dynamic generated file - After JaNeLa corrections "orgen-client.jnlp":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com"    codebase="http://www.orgen.com.br/jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>orgen-client</title>
        <vendor>AtlanticaSoft</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.orgen.com.br/"/>
        <description>Aplicação cliente Orgen</description>
        <icon href="icon.jpeg"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
        <shortcut online="true">
            <desktop />
            <menu submenu="My App"/>
        </shortcut>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <update check="always"/>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8+" java-vm-args="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="lib/orgen-client.jar" version="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" main="true"/>
        <jar href="lib/orgen-client-dependency.jar" version="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"/>
        <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="br.com.atlanticasoft.orgen.client.Main">

      <argument>tenant_id%3D1</argument>
      <argument>jsfsession%3DQvxSCvhgTKST-VkHtAg_AlnQeqeuXnUhP8_iyIo5</argument>
      <argument>ip%3D34.195.218.69</argument>
      <argument>idunidade%3D1</argument>
      <argument>action%3DImprimirLaudo</argument>
      <argument>idproducaoitens%3D1346</argument>
      <argument>locale%3Dpt_BR</argument>
      <argument>contextroot%3D%2F</argument>
      <argument>imprimirpapeltimbrado%3Dtrue</argument>
      <argument>point%3DproducaoConsulta</argument>
      <argument>idusuario%3D20</argument>

   </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Do you use the file naming scheme (<JAR file name>__V<version number>.jar) mentioned in Oracle's docs? In this case your generated file's name has to be orgen-client__V1.0.jar and orgen-client-dependency__V1.0.jar.

Comment: You probably want to avoid multiple downloads of the JAR(s), not the JNLP which is unlikely 80mb? Maybe you put the question a little bit clearer.

Comment: 1) Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). 2) `initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="512m" java-vm-args="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m"` at best this seems redundant, at worst, confusing the JVM. Change it to `initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="512m"` 3) Check that the server is consistently providing the correct 'last updated' date for the resources. 4) @StefanHegny Good point, it looked odd to me as well. the title has now been tweaked. 5) Is the JNLP dynamically generated?

Comment: Thanks, all for reply, i will do some tests in app, changing parameters. Yes, the JNLP is dynamic generated with the same content awalys, @StefanHegny this dependency <jar href="lib/orgen-client-dependency.jar" version="1.0" /> had more than 80mb.

Comment: Hi guys, i pass the JNLP through the JaNeLa, and solve all error questions and make all things we sugest in file, but the JNLP still download all resources, many and many times, i will update the question with my new file content. Thanks to all.

Comment: I just want avoid download the same resources, all the time, the content of JNLP can change, because this he are generated dynamic, but i try simulate the cenario with the same content and he still download all resource.